# how to populate imagecombobox with picture.(Devexpreess Controls )

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I have a table student with a photo field which store images in binary form.
I want to populate my combobox with a all students pics same as we did to populate combobox with names of all students.

```
private void populateData()
{
    studentList=(from s in _ApplicationDB.Students select s).ToList();

        foreach (Student _record in studentList)//.OrderBy(i => i)
        {

            comboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.Add(_record.Name);
            imageComboBoxEdit1.Properties.SmallImages(_record.Photo);//error in this line
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried. Also, when someone tries to help you, don't demand anything. It won't get you anywhere.

Comment: Hi @MaxMommersteeg i have did this till now.
I save pic by using this code in my table
 string path1 = textEditFilePath.Text;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            byte[] picbytes = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(picbytes, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            record.Photo = picbytes;

Comment: I can get names of pic by using this code
  studentList=(from s in _ApplicationDB.Students select s).ToList();

            foreach (Student _record in studentList)//.OrderBy(i => i)
            {

                comboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.Add(_record.Name);}

Comment: But how i populate ImageComboBox by all pics which i save in table

Answer (score 0):

The `imageComboBoxEdit1.Properties.SmallImages` Property is used like a method in your case. You should set the SmallImages like this:

```
imageComboBoxEdit1.Properties.SmallImage = myImageCollection;
```

Then you can Select an Image about the index of selected item.

How this works in detail and with good example is described here:
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsImageComboBoxEdittopic

Comment: how to initialize ImageCollection object by list of images

Comment: ImageCollection is a DevExpress Component. You can find it in the toolbox and add to your Form. You can simply access via items.Add().